# Adding mobile support for existing web based business system

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

We have a business system based on PHP/JQuery/HTML. What would be the best solution for creating a mobile version of the system. Im thinking of making a part of it run on different mobile platforms and came up with presenting web services for the data and jquery mobile for the presentation.

Anyone out there done something similar?